# If $2^{\text{cf } \kappa} < \kappa$, then $\kappa^+$ is the least possible value of $\kappa^{\text{cf } \kappa}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I would like to show that if $2^{\text{cf } \kappa} < \kappa$, then $\kappa^+$ is the least possible value of $\kappa^{\text{cf } \kappa}$ where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal. I'm certain it follows easily, but I'm not seeing it. Any hits?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I just made the correction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is this statement equivalent to saying that $\kappa^+$ (successor) is the least possible value of $\kappa^{\text{cf } k}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why did you not post that as an answer? I didn't see your comment, so I posted it as an answer and now it looks like I copied from you. :/

Comment: @Ahaan: Because I wasn’t sure whether the OP was actually asking that question, or whether there was some typo. I’ve upvoted your answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Haha, thanks. You're very kind.

Comment: @user200593: No, it’s a somewhat more complicated result; check the link in Ahaan’s answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I edited my question. I wasn't aware that those two conditions weren't equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known (as it follows from [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28set_theory%29)) that $ \kappa < \kappa^{\text{cf} \ \kappa} $, where $\kappa$ is any infinite cardinal, so your statement is true.

---

The above refers to the original question, no longer available.

---

To the new question: This statement is also true; see [here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~sinapova/Modified%20Hybrid%20Prikry.pdf).

Comment: This is not Koenig's theorem, it's just the first observable consequence of the theorem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know. I didn't say that it is directly the statement of König's theorem. I simply said that it follows from König's theorem. I've edited to clarify that.

Comment: Sorry. I've edited my question.

Comment: @user200593 Edited answer.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused. Isn't my question asking if $2^{cf \kappa}$ < $\kappa$ implies $k^+ \le \kappa^{cf \kappa}$, in which case it's the same question as the first?

Comment: @user200593: Yes, the question is the same, only vaguer than before. It has nothing to do with Sinapova's excellent work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well this is from Set Theory by Jech. http://i.imgur.com/kXAZA3k.png. I was wondering why he added the condition $2^{cf \kappa} < \kappa$ if the consequent's always true anyway (via Koenig).

Comment: @user200593: I looked that paragraph up (next time it's better to give some reference so the reader can establish additional context if needed as well). I'm not 100% sure as to why Jech wrote that. But note that $\kappa^+\leq\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$, but SCH says that under additional conditions this is the only possible value. It seems to me that Jech was somewhat aiming towards that sort of understanding, but I agree that it's a strange thing to say.